# Hardhat ERC20 transfer failed

Tags: ethereum, solidity, web3js, hardhat

I don't know why the transfer function does not work. I tried npx hardhat test but it seems to fail when transferring.

```
function deposit(address token, uint256 amount) external onlyOwner {
    uint256 balance = ERC20(token).balanceOf(msg.sender);
    console.log(token, balance);
    require(balance > amount, "not enough money to deposit");
    ERC20(token).approve(address(this), amount);
    ERC20(token).transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), amount);
}
```

This is the hardhat JavaScript code which executes the contract

```js
await WETH.transfer(arb.address, ethers.utils.parseUnits("2", "ether"));

await IWETH.deposit({
  value: ethers.utils.parseUnits("100.0", "ether"),
});

await arb
  .connect(owner)
  .deposit(
    "0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2",
    ethers.utils.parseUnits("2", "ether")
  );
```

I seems like it failed at `ERC20(token).transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), amount);`

Comment: at solidity, we can use  `console.log(token, balance);` ?

Comment: @MERN Only if you're using the [Hardhat console](https://hardhat.org/tutorial/debugging-with-hardhat-network.html). In non-local (or to be more precise, non-Hardhat) environments, this expression is not available.

Comment: `address payable` instead of `address` for token in the argument? Does that work?